# xts conversion fails on 7 line data frame

Tags: r, xts

I am trying to read a csv file and create an xts object. The xts conversion function fails on an 7 line input file. The error is:

Error in xts(Lagoon$Inst, Lagoon$time) :
'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'

The code is:

```
require(xts)
> Lagoon <- read.csv("Mara/csv/test/X8.csv")
> Lagoon
                 time Inst
1 00:45:00 03/10/2019 5.76
2 01:00:00 03/10/2019 5.77
3 01:15:00 03/10/2019 5.81
4 01:30:00 03/10/2019 5.61
5 01:45:00 03/10/2019 5.46
6 02:00:00 03/10/2019 5.40
7 02:15:00 03/10/2019 5.38
> Lagoon$time <- as.POSIXlt(Lagoon$time, format = "%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%Y")
> Lagoon
                 time Inst
1 2019-03-10 00:45:00 5.76
2 2019-03-10 01:00:00 5.77
3 2019-03-10 01:15:00 5.81
4 2019-03-10 01:30:00 5.61
5 2019-03-10 01:45:00 5.46
6 2019-03-10 02:00:00 5.40
7 2019-03-10 02:15:00 5.38
> xtsLagoon <- xts(Lagoon$Inst,Lagoon$time)
Error in xts(Lagoon$Inst, Lagoon$time) : 
  'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'
>
```

I have tried to slice and dice the real input file into smaller and smaller chunks; the above csv file is a minimum reproducible example. Removing one line of data creates a file that *does* convert properly into an xts object.

Note that the Lagoon data frame looks OK  when I list it before the attempted its conversion (no NA, Nan, or Inf).

My version of xts is the latest (0.12.1)

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug in the xts conversion function? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of the 'Lagoon'

Comment: Use `as.POSIXct` instead of `as.POSIXlt` as the POSIXlt returns a list

Comment: If I use `POSIXct`, then the last two values are converted to `NA` - `as.POSIXct(Lagoon$time, format = "%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%Y")
[1] "2019-03-10 00:45:00 CST" "2019-03-10 01:00:00 CST" "2019-03-10 01:15:00 CST" "2019-03-10 01:30:00 CST" "2019-03-10 01:45:00 CST"
[6] NA                        NA`, is it because of time change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input file is not shown in the question so we will assume we have the file generated reproducibly in the Note at the end.  With that use `read.csv.zoo` and be sure to specify the time zone as `"UTC"` because in your local time zone 02:15 does not exist on 03/10/2019 due to the change from standard to daylight savings time.

(Alternately use the code in the question except (1) first set the session's time zone to UTC using `Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")` and (2) use `as.POSIXct` rather than `as.POSIXlt`.)

```
library(xts)

z <- read.csv.zoo("X8.csv", format = "%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%Y", tz = "UTC")
x <- as.xts(z)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "time,Inst
00:45:00 03/10/2019,5.76
01:00:00 03/10/2019,5.77
01:15:00 03/10/2019,5.81
01:30:00 03/10/2019,5.61
01:45:00 03/10/2019,5.46
02:00:00 03/10/2019,5.40
02:15:00 03/10/2019,5.38"
cat(Lines, file = "X8.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue from the conversion of last two elements (as it returns `NA` with `as.POSIXct` - perhaps due to daylight savings).  An option is to use `parse_date` (`parsedate`) to convert to `Datetime` object and then use `xts`

```
library(parsedate)
Lagoon$time <- parse_date(Lagoon$time)
xts::xts(Lagoon$Inst,Lagoon$time)
                [,1]
2019-03-10 00:45:00 5.76
2019-03-10 01:00:00 5.77
2019-03-10 01:15:00 5.81
2019-03-10 01:30:00 5.61
2019-03-10 01:45:00 5.46
2019-03-10 02:00:00 5.40
2019-03-10 02:15:00 5.38
```

#### data

```
Lagoon <- structure(list(time = c("00:45:00 03/10/2019", "01:00:00 03/10/2019", 
"01:15:00 03/10/2019", "01:30:00 03/10/2019", "01:45:00 03/10/2019", 
"02:00:00 03/10/2019", "02:15:00 03/10/2019"), Inst = c(5.76, 
5.77, 5.81, 5.61, 5.46, 5.4, 5.38)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```